Creating a merged dataset from a subset of variables from multiple hypertables with TimescaleDB - continuous aggregate
I wanted to see if anyone can suggest ways around this before I give up on it entirely as an option.
We have a Postgres (14) TimescaleDB database. It has several hypertables, each of which is populated by different instruments. The tables have columns timestamp, field1, field2, ... , fieldN, where each field is a measured value (could be a temperature, a speed, a direction (0-360 degrees), etc).
We would like to create a merged dataset of a subset of fields from multiple tables. They should the aggregated to the same timestamp at a 5s interval. As far as I can tell, this is not possible using the continuous aggregate feature of TimescaleDB because:

Continuous aggregate does not allow CTEs or joins on hypertables. Even if I was to generate a continuous aggregate for each table that we want to include, the timestamps would not necessarily be synchronised in the final product?
Continuous aggregate does not allow functions that are not IMMUTABLE. We are using atan / cos / sin to make sure headings and directions are averaged correctly across 359-0 degrees, and timescale complains about it.

Can anyone suggest ways around these blockers I've run into? Or alternatives to my backup - having one big view query that is called regularly by a CRON job?

I think you can overcome this issue creating a hypertable to track the joined data. Remember that continuous aggregates are hypertables.
Make a user defined action for every source of data to feed the hypertable independently. Each action can be scheduled independently but all feed same hypertable.

Here is an POC of the idea: https://github.com/jonatas/sql-snippets/blob/master/cagg_multiple_hypertables.sql

Thank you for your effort on this @jonatasdp , I've been on leave since I posted it. I'll give the SQL a test now.
